# css3 animation start and pause shaking

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I use css3 animation to rotate a div element infinitely, and use animation-play-state to pause or play the animation. but when the animation pause or play, the animation div will shake somewhat, how to fix this?

```js
$('#start').click(function() {
  $('.rotate').removeClass('stop');
  $('.rotate').addClass('play');
});
$('#stop').click(function() {
  $('.rotate').removeClass('play');
  $('.rotate').addClass('stop');
});
```

```css
.rotate {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-tranform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.cover {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.playing {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}

.stop {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cover rotate'></div>
<button id='start'>start</button>
<button id='stop'>stop</button>
```

Comment: It's not shaking for me. What browser are you on? How big is the viewport?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I use the last release chrome browser. the div animation is good at beginning, but it will start shake when it rotates for a while...

Comment: Still can't reproduce